# Bot Framework: How to stop a ChoicePrompt from RePrompting

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, web-chat

I developed a Webpage via React in which a Webchat-Bot and the React App interact. The React App contains a Timer, that should stop any Dialog that is running in that moment. It does this in sending an event over Direct-Line.
Anyway, I get the unwanted behavior that if the bot logic is in a Waterfall where the step is a (Choice-)Prompt, the Question gets reprompted. (Because it didt receive the required answer from the user). My question is:

How do I stop a ChoicePrompt from Reprompting?

When the Bot receives the 'timeout'-event, it stops the current dialog with`await endDialog()` and begins a new dialog that sends new messages. After the next user Input, the Prompt from before pops up. So I assume, the Prompt in the background still waits for one of the answers, and because it didnt receive it, it starts again or reprompt.

I tried to put maxRetries to 0:

```
var options = {maxRetries: '0'};
await step.prompt(CONFIRM_PROMPT, `text abc..`, ['sure', 'not sure'], options);
```

code snipplet for the event that pops up..

```
async onTurn(turnContext) {
const dc = await this.dialogs.createContext(turnContext);
..
if (turnContext.activity.name === 'time-feedback') {
    ..
    await dc.endDialog(); // when a choice-prompt is active, it keeps reprompting, before the next line gets activated. I wish to end the reprompt and current (waterfall dialog) immediately
    await dc.beginDialog(PromptForStartingNew); // start a new waterfall dialog

}
```

Comment: what do you want to happen when the dialog receives an input that isn't one of the choices? just end the dialog? what do you do with the choice?

Comment: @Naadof i want that the Prompt-dialog is cancelled in a way that it is not waiting for an answer that contains one of the choices. I dont need any result or input regarding this question, as i want to start a new dialog. Do you know a possible way for this?

Comment: Do you want to clear the whole dialog stack or just pop one dialog off the stack?

Comment: only this one dialog..

Comment: @KyleDelaney, Naadof
Do you have a hint how I could solve the issue? Do you need more information to understand my point?

Comment: Sorry, still a little confused - if you don't care about the answer, can you not just end the dialog yourself via step.endDialog()? Or change the choice prompt to a text prompt that doesn't have validation, and when you get a response, regardless of what it is, end the dialog there?

Comment: If you're only ending the active dialog, you're only ending the choice prompt, which means the waterfall dialog becomes the active dialog, and it wouldn't be able to do anything because it's depending on the result of the prompt. Can you clarify what your desired behavior is? Do you want the waterfall to continue with a default value? Do you want to pop the waterfall off the stack too? How will you determine how many dialogs to end if you don't want to clear the whole stack?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Sorry for the late response. Ja it is still an actual issue.

Comment: @KyleDelaney. With the event that the bot gets from the website, I want that the Choice Prompt ends, as well as the whole waterfall the Choice Prompt is located in. 
I tried this with the endDialog(). I understand your first sentence that this is not enough!?
I catch the relevant event from the website and start a new waterfall dialog which I want to continue with.

Comment: So to be clear, you want to respond to the event by popping only the current dialog off the stack, and if the current dialog was a prompt then you also want to pop its parent dialog off the stack. Is that correct? Are you sure you don't want to clear the whole dialog stack before adding a new dialog? Can you show the code that you're using currently to respond to the event?

Comment: the ChoicePrompt is a step of waterfall dialog. If the event pops in, I wish to end the whole waterfall dialog (regardless if the current step was waiting for an answer from a Prompt).  I edited my question with the code snipplet. The code does what i want (end the current waterfall dialog and start a new one) but only if the current dialog wasnt a Prompt.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

The [`replaceDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs/dialogcontext?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#replacedialog-string--object-) function does exactly what you're trying to do. It ends the active dialog and then begins a new one but without resuming whatever dialog is next-highest on the stack.

> This method is conceptually equivalent to calling endDialog() and then immediately calling beginDialog(). The difference is that the parent dialog is not resumed or otherwise notified that the dialog it started has been replaced.

I suspect some of the problems you're encountering are because `resumeDialog` is being called for the waterfall before you're beginning the new dialog. However, it doesn't make sense to me that the waterfall would stay on its current step and call the same choice prompt again. What I expect to happen is for the waterfall to proceed to the next step and start a new prompt, and then your interrupting dialog is put on the stack on top of that next step's prompt. Then when your interrupting dialog ends, the next step's prompt will prompt again, rather than the first step's prompt. It's hard to know what's really happening without seeing the rest of your code, but that distinction may be irrelevant if my solution works for you.

Since you've said you want to end the whole waterfall rather than just the prompt, you'll need a little bit more than `replaceDialog`. You want to end the active dialog and then replace the dialog beneath that, but only if the active dialog is a prompt and the next dialog is a waterfall. You can try something like this:

```
// Check if there are at least 2 dialogs on the stack
if (dc.stack.length > 1) {
    const activeInstance = dc.activeDialog;
    const parentInstance = dc.stack[dc.stack.length - 2];
    const activeDialog = dc.findDialog(activeInstance.id);
    const parentDialog = dc.findDialog(parentInstance.id);

    if (activeDialog instanceof Prompt && parentDialog instanceof WaterfallDialog)
    {
        // Calling endDialog is probably unnecessary for prompts
        // but it's good practice to do it anyway
        await activeDialog.endDialog(turnContext, activeInstance, DialogReason.endCalled);
        // Remove the prompt from the stack without resuming the waterfall
        dc.stack.pop();
    }
}

// Replace the waterfall (or any active dialog) with your interrupting dialog
await dc.replaceDialog(PromptForStartingNew);
```